# Want to add drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

[image: error in image][image: now this is the folder where all the files are placed.Tell me how you gonna give the path of javascript/CSS file.][image: Error Damn!!][image: index2][image: index1][image: JS code][image: This is the image that I am getting by his code in SublimeText but as i am clicking on Newest *Created drop down* it is not showing the drop down list.]I have read the tutorials and have gone through the other posts too. I have made a page where on the side bar I have created a list item with the name "Drop Down" and I want as I click on it opens a drop down list and have done coding according to it. But issue is that drop down list is not coming. And I really am not getting the exactly the problem is.

Any Help would be appreciated.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aw330go1/8/)

Code and Snippet Given below

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  buildPager: function(slideIndex){
    switch(slideIndex){
      case 0:
        return '<img src="2012 Outdoor Classic @ Ivor Winn Stadium.jpg">';
      case 1:
        return '<img src="3rd.jpg">';
      case 2:
        return '<img src="bxDP8.png">';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css")
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }   
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';

  background-image: url("/home/kamna/admin page/bubble_f2.jpg");
} 
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


div#header {
  width: 500%;
  height: 50px;

  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {

  margin-top: 50px;
  margin;left:15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.logo a {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #000;
}

.logo a span {
  font-weight: 300;
}

div#container {
  width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #171717;
  float: left;
  color:#fff; /* change to whatever you want */
}
.content {
  width: auto;
  margin-left:250px;
  height: 500px;
  backgroud-color: #008000;
  color: #000;
  padding: 15px;
}



.content p {
  width:auto;
  font-size :0.73em;


}

}


div#box {
  margin-top:15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div#box .box-top {
  color:#fff;
  text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #000;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  padding:5px;
  padding-left:15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

div#box .box-panel {
  padding:15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color:#333;
}


ul#nav {

}

ul#nav li {
  list-style: none;

}

ul#nav li a {
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0A0A0A;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition:0.2s;
  -o-transition:0.2;
  transition:0.2s;
}

ul#nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #030303;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left:30px;
}


ul#nav li a.selected{
  background-color: #030303;
  color:#fff;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}

#center {
  margin:0px auto;
  width:960px; 
  height:auto;
  border:5px solid black;
  padding:10px;

}

#One {
  margin-right: 0px;

}

#Two {
  margin-left: 20px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
#Three {
  margin-left: 20px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
#Four{
  margin-left: 20px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

a.mobile{
  display block;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000;
  text-align: center;
  padding:7px;
  border-bottom:1px #fff;


}

a.mobile: active{
  background-color:#4a4a4a;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> SpaceCar </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/global.css"/> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale:1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="srcipts/general.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header"> 
      <div class="logo"> <a href="#">Space<span>Run
        </span></a></div>
    </div> 
    <a class="mobile">MENU</a>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <ul id="nav">
          <li><a class="selected" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Maruti</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hyundai</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">RangeRover</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Purchases</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!--<button onclick="addimage();"> Click</button>-->
      </div>


      <div class="content">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <p> alright this is your dashboard</p>
        <div id="box">
          <div class="box-top">News</div>
          <div class="box-panel">
            this is some simple news ikdnksnd
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="box">
          <div class="box-top">News</div>
          <div class="box-panel">
            what is idshfknsdkjfnjsdnkfnsdn
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="box">
          <div class="box-top">News</div>
          <div class="box-panel">
            o i really khdkasndksnk is o asdjbaskjbdkasbdmaskdbas 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="center">
          <img src="images (1).jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="One"/>
          <img src="fisker-karma.jpg" style="width:189px;height:170px" id="Two"/>
          <img src="images.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="Three"/>
          <img src="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="Four"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a "," instead of a "." here

```
$(".sidebar").slideToggle('fast');
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/aw330go1/4/)

Also you forgot to include jQuery library in your JSFiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aw330go1/8/ please review this code... and here again dropdown list is not showing anything

Comment: You mix native Javascript with jQuery here .. Why not using the simple slideToggle() function to make the animation ? It's the same HTML code

Comment: I tried but it is not happening. Could you please show it in Fiddle?

Comment: Thanks and I am really sorry but you are using my earlier by mistaken given fiddle.. There i do not even have drop down list item and code. https://jsfiddle.net/aw330go1/8/ . this is the fiddle that i have made for drop down and tried slideToggle() also but it isn't working. kindly make an updation in this fiddle.. Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: R/Sir
i want my dropdown list to get open with the three sublist items. and the fiddle which you have shown me is exactly the same as of mine and when I click on *dropdown* list item it is not showing anything in dropdown list. Did you get my question ?

Comment: Yes, it wasn't very clear before you say it ;) 
So it is simply the same logic as the previous code : https://jsfiddle.net/aw330go1/10/ 
I add comment to show you the relevant part.

Comment: Yes it worked in fiddle but again the same issue in  sublime text. there again it is not working. it is not showing any dropdown menu. What could be the reason for it? i have added the same code for it.

Comment: Can you do screenshots of your code in sublime text and browser ? Otherwise I can't guess.

Comment: I updated my question above and the last item is *NEWEST*. i have changed the name of Dropdown> Newest. Rest the code is same as of the Fiddle.

Comment: Do you have errors in your console when you use the browser inspector ? Do you include the jQuery library ? Do you put `$(document).ready()` function around your jQuery script like this  https://jsfiddle.net/aw330go1/14/
?

Comment: Yes.. done all... i either can show you through skype. if you do not mind sharing your Skype ID

Comment: Just one more screenshot of your index.html file and I can give you the solution :)

Comment: added in the questions. :)

Comment: Seems correct ... Your scripts (jQuery and general) paths are corrects ? Can you do a screenshot of the console panel in your inspector browser ?

Comment: You have a typo error !!! `srcipts` instead of `scripts` to load the general.js file :)

Comment: I already have defined myFunction() then why is it showing error in line 30 of HTML code? :(

Comment: Did you read my previous comment ? You have a typo error when calling your script general.js. That's why you have an error when you call myFunction() on line 30 of your index.html file

Comment: Yes I made the corrections thank you :) and I   think there is some issue with the path .... but i am giving the right path as per my knowledge..

Comment: You can see in the console that both JS files are not found. Also don't make space in your folder or it could be misinterpreted as this char : %20
Put the subject solved if it's ok for you :)

Comment: how will you give the path for the above screenshot for JS n CSS file,. Just want to reconfirm whether I am right or not.

Comment: should be admin_page or adminPage but NO spaces in your folder like I said before. And your folder is script not scripts so be rigorous with that in your HTML file, otherwise it wont works. :)

Comment: Ahhh. I didn't realize the name of my folder. Thanks Alot for devoting me your precious time to me. Its working now.  :) :) Do you have the knowledge of JSON and AJAX? As what I am thinking is to make a JSON object where i can have Car models.and then load json through AJAX. and populate the models on my page. Did you get the idea that what exactly I need?

Comment: You're welcome ! Put the subject as solved please ! :) 
You can check documentation of ajax with jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and many other websites examples first and if you get troubles with it, post a question on SO. But it's better to try first ;)

Comment: :D Well ofcourse I'm gonna try it first and afterwards only I'll ask if any problem comes. now one more trouble.. In CSS i set a picture as the background image. Now its not coming in background. body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  
   background-image: url("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1.jpg");
}  any issue with this what i have written in CSS?? :(

Comment: One advice : use the browser inspector to see that. It will be written if it couldn't find the image. In the elements tab, you can check on the body tag if the image is loaded. An other advice, avoid name an image like this, it's not very easy to verify the name like this ;)

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND >>> This is the error that I am getting and i tried .. ../images/bubble_f2.jpg in this way too i did try but its not coming. earlier the background was coming as you must have seen in screenshot above. And now its not coming.

Comment: It's on the same folder so it must be `background: url('bubble_f2.jpg');` no ?

Comment: Yes it was. then i thought to move it in different folder and then to give a path. go through the screenshot and see..where am i wrong. :(

Comment: Where is global.css ? In "styles" folder I suppose. So the path should be then `background: url("../bubble_f2.jpg");`
We have to avoid extended discussions in comments. It's not relevant of the originally issue.

Comment: :D :D Its done. :) first thing i added the image in another folder and was giving the incorrect path.. and yes things are done. If would have to ask things about AJAX.Will make another thread. Thanks once again. :)